# How do I reset my network share permissions?

Tags: networking, permissions

Our server has a number of shared folders for the different departments to store stuff in. Now I have an account that I can use to access the folders available to me and things used to work fine... I'd navigate to the folder, enter my name/pass and get access to whatever I needed.

One day, I logged into the network share with an account that had less permissions than my own, and ever since I've only been able to use the permissions of that one user account. I can't seem to find where I can reset my network share permissions/account so that I can re-enter it whenever I navigate to the shares.

The only things I can seem to find online are how to change folder permissions on my local drive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question belongs on superuser.  I know this because I asked the same question there: https://superuser.com/questions/10790/delete-cached-windows-network-share-passwords

> On Windows XP, click Start - Settings - Control Panel - User Accounts - Your username - Manage network passwords (on the left hand side). You can add, edit and remove saved credentials here for accessing network resources here.

Answer (score 1):

If the answer in David Mackintosh's post doesn't do it for you try this:

1. Open a cmd window
2. Type `net use /d \\myserver\mysharename`

This will clear things, including cached authentication, to that share.  The next time you try to connect to that share you should be able to use your proper authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another version if you have a problem similar to mine.

On Windows 7, if you, like me, have saved credentials to access various shares throughout your network, your credentials may become stale and stop letting you do things like copy files around and not tell you why.  It only says Access Denied.  You have to delete your credentials from the Credential manager (Start/Control Panel/Credential Manager).  Locate the server in question in the list, drop the arrow down on the right, then click Remove from vault.  You might need to restart, but Windows should then either let you in with your base credentials, or prompt for better credentials.